# Can a non multi-engine rated pilot get a complex endorsement in a multi-engine aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, faa, type-ratings

I was wondering if a pilot with only an SEP can get his/her complex endorsement in a multi-engine aircraft? I would guess not but since I didn't find any clear info or FAR that sates you can't, I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: I think you are asking if a SEP pilot can receive training in a multi engine aircraft to fulfill the requirements of a complex aircraft endorsement without fulfilling the requirements of the multi engine type endorsement. I assume that would mean demonstrating operation of the flaps, retractable gear, and controllable propellers without demonstrating single engine operations. That is an interesting scenario.

Comment: @MikeSowsun That's exactly what I'm asking, sorry if it wasn't clear. And yes, its an interesting scenario indeed. From a logical standpoint I don't even know if it makes much sense but I couldn't find any regulation on the mater.

Answer (score 4):

If the airplane meets the definition, which almost all multi-engine pistons will, then you can get your complex endorsement. There is even one training center that advertises getting your multi and complex at the same time.

> **§61.1   Applicability and definitions.**
>
> Complex airplane means an airplane that has a retractable landing
>   gear, flaps, and a controllable pitch propeller, including airplanes
>   equipped with an engine control system consisting of a digital
>   computer and associated accessories for controlling the engine and
>   propeller, such as a full authority digital engine control; or, in the
>   case of a seaplane, flaps and a controllable pitch propeller,
>   including seaplanes equipped with an engine control system consisting
>   of a digital computer and associated accessories for controlling the
>   engine and propeller, such as a full authority digital engine control.

---

> §**61.31   Type rating requirements, additional training, and
>   authorization requirements.**
>
> (e) Additional training required for operating complex airplanes. (1)
>   Except as provided in paragraph (e)(2) of this section, no person may
>   act as pilot in command of a complex airplane, unless the person has—
>
> (i) Received and logged ground and flight training from an authorized
>   instructor in a complex airplane, or in a full flight simulator or
>   flight training device that is representative of a complex airplane,
>   and has been found proficient in the operation and systems of the
>   airplane; and
>
> (ii) Received a one-time endorsement in the pilot's logbook from an
>   authorized instructor who certifies the person is proficient to
>   operate a complex airplane.

---

> **[Complex Airplane Endorsement](http://www.spirit-aviation.com/multi-engine-rating-complex-airplane-endorsement/)**
>
> Learn to fly aircraft with retractable landing gear, controllable
>   flaps, and a controllable propeller using our Piper Seminole PA-44-180
>   airplane. You can earn your complex endorsement, or combine your
>   training to earn your complex endorsement and multi-engine rating.*

Comment: Your last paragraph appears to be a quote, perhaps from the site linked above it, but isn't quoted. If it's not a quote, then it sounds like advertising for... something.

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the original question:  “Can a SEP pilot receive training in a multi engine aircraft to fulfill the requirements of a complex aircraft endorsement without fulfilling the requirements of the multi engine type endorsement.” This would mean demonstrating operation of the flaps, retractable gear, and controllable propellers without demonstrating single engine operations.

Comment: @MikeSowsun Not sure why it doesn’t answer the question. 61.31 says that you need training in a complex airplane. If the FAA wanted to restrict you to single engine, they would say so. There are several places in Part 61 where they use the restriction “aircraft category, class, type (if required)” so if they wanted to place restrictions on the type of airplane you can get a complex endorsement in, they certainly know how to do it.

Comment: I guess I just wanted to see it spelled out: “Yes, you can do your Complex Aircraft Endorsement in a multi engine aircraft without demonstrating engine out proficiency.” Your answer implies it, but doesn’t really say it.